# Delphi upload to https and verify smart card certificate

Tags: delphi, ssl, ssl-certificate, indy

I'm using Delphi XE and 10.1 Berlin.
I need to sent xml to HTTPS (using Indy 10) and verify my smart card certificate.
In 10.1 Berlin, this code works but i get error SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE: Certificate verify failed.
Do I need assign RootCertFile, CertFile or KeyFile, and how to do it from smart card or cert store?

This is part of my code:

```
procedure TFR_O1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Req: TStream;
  S, xml_file: String;
  SSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin

  OpenDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);

  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    xml_file := OpenDialog1.FileName;
  end;

  Req := TStringStream.Create(xml_file, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    SSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    try
      SSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      SSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      SSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [sslvrfPeer,sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert,sslvrfClientOnce];
      SSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

      //SSL1.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := '';
      //SSL1.SSLOptions.CertFile := '';
      //SSL1.SSLOptions.KeyFile := '';
      SSL1.OnVerifyPeer := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer;

      IdHTTP1.IOHandler := SSL1;

      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
      IdHTTP1.Request.Charset := 'UTF-8';

      S := IdHTTP1.Post('https://11.11.11.11:11/api/upload', Req);
    finally
      SSL1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Req.Free;
  end;

end;

function TFR_O.IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1VerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
begin
ShowMessage(Certificate.FingerprintAsString);
ShowMessage(Certificate.Subject.OneLine);
ShowMessage(Certificate.Issuer.OneLine);

  if ADepth = 0 then
  begin
    Result := AOk;
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

I have been searching on web, but I haven't find any solution or example how to get cert from smart card.

Comment: What is Delphi XE10? Do you mean Delphi 10 Seattle? If so, then say so.

Comment: Sorry, Delphi 10.1 Berrlin